# Biblatex: make footcite look the same for all bibtex types

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

In the following MWE the title of both citations have a different format. One is italic, the other one in quotations.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
bibencoding=utf8,
bibstyle=authoryear,
citestyle=authortitle-icomp,    
]{biblatex}%
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\autocite{yoon}, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure\autocite{aristotle:anima} dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I make all "footcitations" look the same, but leave the `\printbibliography` output untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appearance of the title in the footnote in the `authortitle-icomp` is controlled by the `citetitle` formatting directive for a title  (i.e., `\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`), which is  then redefined for specific entry types (`article`, `inbox` , `in collection`, `in proceedings`, `patent`, `thesis`, `unpublished`, `suppbook`, `suppcollection` and `suppperiodical`).

Thus one has to refined

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,
     inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,suppbook,
     suppcollection,suppperiodical]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If one wants the same style for all entry types, the starred version of `\DeclareFieldFormat` is a bit more comfortable, because it does not require one to know which types might be different. So I would use `\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`.